# Why is switch/case for characters not working?

Tags: java, switch-statement, character, case

Ignoring lines 1-55, can someone tell me why my switch isn't working for characters ' v ' and ' | ' whenever they appear? I put some print line statements (line 57, 58) to see what's going on, but they don't even get executed!

Only line 56 executes and then it continues reading the file for more characters, skipping the process for ' v ' and ' | ' characters...

Every other switch works fine, excluding those two.

input is a BufferedReader for a text file that looks like this

test.txt

```
50
5
3
0
s-o o-o-o
| v v | v
o-o-o-oho
v |   v |
o-o-o-e-o
```

Here is the relevant portion of code:

```
// loop through remaining lines of file
while (line != null) {
    // get characters in the line
    for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++) {

        // if character is even, it is a node
        ch = line.charAt(j);
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("character even and is: " + ch);
            switch (ch) {
            case 's':
                System.out.println("s test worked");
                break;
            case 'e':
                System.out.println("e test worked");
                break;
            case 'o': // increase the node count
                break;
            }
        }

        // else character is odd, it is an edge
        else {
            System.out.println("character odd and is: " + ch);
            System.out.println(ch == 'v'); // Line 57
            System.out.println(ch == '|'); // Line 58
            switch (ch) {
            // horizontal wall
            case 'h':
                System.out.println("h test worked");
                break;
            // horizontal hall
            case '-':
                System.out.println("- test worked");
                break;
            // vertical wall
            case 'v':
                System.out.println("v test worked");
                break;
            // vertical hall
            case '|':
                System.out.println("| test worked");
                break;
            // unbreakable wall
            case ' ': // don't do anything
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    line = input.readLine();
}
```

Here [is a link to complete, compilable code, given that you give the program the text file as an argument](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/44f551cf57b8ba9309cb).

Comment: Could you trim down the posted code to just what's required to understand and reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your code assumes that all edges are located in odd positions. However, this is correct only about the horizontal edges; the vertical edges (i.e. ones on odd-numbered lines) are located in even positions.

You can fix this by adding a line counter, like this:

```
int lineCounter = 0;
while (line != null) {
    // get characters in the line
    for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++) {
        // if character is even, it is a node
        ch = line.charAt(j);
        if ((lineCounter+j) % 2 == 0) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
    line = input.readLine();
    lineCounter++;
}
```

This code looks for edges in odd positions on even-numbered lines, and in even positions on odd-numbered lines.